# how to get file extensions of array elements in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm trying to get the file extension of image columns in my database but I get this error :

> pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

this is my controller code below:

```
$news = DB::table('news')
       ->select('image')
       ->where('id', '=', 'user_id')
       ->get();


$file = $news;
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
return view('pages.index',compact('ext'));
```

this is my views:

```
@if($ext == 'mp4' || $ext == 'mov' || $ext == 'vob' || $ext == 'mpeg' || $ext == '3gp' || $ext == 'avi' || $ext == 'wmv' || $ext == 'mov' || $ext == 'amv' || $ext == 'svi' || $ext == 'flv' || $ext == 'mkv' || $ext == 'webm' || $ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'asf')
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="{{URL::asset('upload/news/'.$topnews->image) }}" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
@else
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('upload/news/'.$topnews->image) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="" width="320" height="240">
@endif
```

this is my route:

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

Comment: So iterate over the array, no?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your array and apply `pathinfo` to each element of array:

```
$extensions = [];
foreach ($news as $file) {
    $extensions[$file] = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

Comment: i get undefined variable extensions in my views, probably because is not global. so how can i load the new values of the $extension variables to my views

Comment: Like any other variables.

Comment: thanks for your response but i tried printing the variable $extensions but nothing printed. seems null

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a `value` function to receive a value directly from a query.

Change your query to

```
 $news = DB::table('news')
        ->select('image')
        ->where('id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->value('image');
```

You may also omit `select` because value already does that

```
 $news = DB::table('news')
        ->where('id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->value('image');
```

[Documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results)

If your Laravel version does not support `value`, then use `first`

```
 $news = DB::table('news')
        ->select('image')
        ->where('id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->first()->image;
```

Comment: issue i'm having is here: $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
the $file is an array and gives out an error